# postgresql "idle in transaction" with all locks granted

Tags: sql, postgresql, locking

A very simple delete (by key) on a small table (700 rows) every now and then stays "idle in transaction" for minutes (takes milliseconds usually) even though all the locks are marked as "granted".

What can I do to pinpoint what causes it?
I'm using this select:

```
  SELECT a.datname,
     c.relname,
     l.transactionid,
     l.mode,
     l.GRANTED,
     a.usename,
     a.waiting,
     a.query, 
     a.query_start,
     age(now(), a.query_start) AS "age", 
     a.pid 
FROM  pg_stat_activity a
 JOIN pg_locks         l ON l.pid = a.pid
 JOIN pg_class         c ON c.oid = l.relation
ORDER BY a.query_start;
```

which shows a lot of "RowExclusiveLock"s but all are granted... so I don't see what is causing this spikes of delays.

Comment: idle in transaction means you did not run `commit/rollback/end` or are connected to the pool with transaction sharing

Comment: the transaction is handled by Spring  @Transaction, and it works ok usually, but every now and then stays in this state for minutes

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is a problem of the application server.

Sessions are in state "idle in transaction" when the application does not end the transaction with `COMMIT` or `ROLLBACK`. This is to be considered a bug in the application.

The locks remain (and are of course granted, otherwise the session could not be idle) until the transaction ends.

From PostgreSQL 9.6 on, you can set the parameter [`idle_in_transaction_session_timeout`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-IDLE-IN-TRANSACTION-SESSION-TIMEOUT) to terminate such transactions automatically with a `ROLLBACK`, but that is a band-aid to avoid problems on the database rather than a solution.

Comment: so it's impossible that the app is actually executing the query? "Idle in transaction" means that the query (delete) has already been done and returned, but the transaction has not been committed?

Comment: Yes, exactly. The SQL statement has finished, the application has not yet committed, and the database is waiting for the next statement in the transaction.

Comment: Doesn't PosGres have auto commit enabled by default? Why should we run COMMIT or ROLLBACK ?

Comment: Yes, it does. But unless you explicitly start a transaction somewhere, the connection can never be in state "idle in transaction".

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe this is quite an old post, but we are seeing this in our application. Also we are seeing a couple of OOM errors. Could the app process dying OOM be a cause of these idle DB transactions?

Comment: @AxelTheGerman Yes. Reduce `tcp_keepalives_idle` to make them die sooner.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe thanks, will give that a try. Just looked into the currently idle transactions in production and there seem to be much more than we have had OOM issues though, so there must be another reason. We currently have over 30 transactions in idle - is that a big concern? https://imgur.com/a/5CptjjQ

Comment: Maybe you should open a question for that (with more details).

Answer (score 0):

It could also be due to a combination of:

1. exhaustion of a connection pool
2. Transactions within transactions
3. Implicit postgres transactions within transactions

This article opened my eyes on this issue https://www.birdie.care/blog/birdie-engineering-update

This explains why there are no deadlocks in the database itself. It's only because app's connection pool ceiling is reached.