# postgres "idle in transaction" for 13 hours

Tags: postgresql

We recently saw a few queries "idle in transaction" for quite some time

```
 pid  | usename |        state        | duration | application_name | wait_event | wait_event_type
------+---------+---------------------+----------+------------------+------------+----------------
31620 | results | idle in transaction | 12:52:23 | bin/rails        |            |
```

That is almost 13 hours idle in transaction.

Any idea what causes them to get stuck in idle, or how to dig deeper? We did notice some OOM errors for background jobs.

There are also a lot of "idle" queries, but thanks for the comments, those seem to be fine:
[image: idle transactions in postgres]

In [postgresql "idle in transaction" with all locks granted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44908010/postgresql-idle-in-transaction-with-all-locks-granted/44908655) @LaurenzAlbe was pointing out the idle session timeout configuration option as a band-aid, but I'd rather understand this issue than hide it.

thanks!

PS: our application is ruby on rails and we use a mix of active record and custom SQL

EDIT: original title was "idle in transaction", the queries are actually just idle most of the time and not in transaction, sorry about that

EDIT #2: found the 13 hour idle in transaction process

Comment: None of those are idle in transaction, just idle, which isn't by itself a problem.  Do you actually see any processes with state 'idle in transaction'?

Comment: "Idle" means there's no active query, that's all. Unless your application is using every connection 100% of the time for something this is what you'll see. If you do see 100% utilization that's usually a sign you need a better server as the queries are probably backlogged.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These sessions are actually all idle, so they are no problem.

`idle` is significantly different from `idle in transaction`: the latter is an open transaction that holds locks and blocks `VACUUM`, the first is harmless.

The OOM errors must have a different reason.

You should configure the machine so that

```
shared_buffers + max_connections * work_mem <= available RAM
```

Comment: sorry about the confusion. seems we have a lot of "idle" queries which are fine.
But we did have that 13 hour "idle in transaction" query which we ended up just killing. this might be the one caused by OOM? Will have to correlate the timing of events.

Comment: Sessions idle in transaction may have some memory allocated, but it shouldn't grow. Also it shouldn't cause other sessions to use more RAM.

Comment: ist it really `shared_buffers + max_connections * work_mem`, or maybe `(shared_buffers + max_connections) * work_mem` ?

Comment: @vms Without the parentheses.