# What can cause "idle in transaction" for "BEGIN" statements

Tags: node.js, postgresql, pg-promise

We have a node.js application that connects via pg-promise to a Postgres 11 server - all processes are running on a single cloud server in docker containers.
Sometimes we hit a situation where the application does not react anymore.

The last time this happened, I had a little time to check the db via pgadmin and it showed that the connections were `idle in transaction` with statement `BEGIN` and an exclusive lock of `virtualxid`
[image] 
[image]

I think the situation is like this:

1. the application has started a transaction by sending the `BEGIN` sql command to the db
2. the db got this command and started a new transaction and thus acquired an exclusive lock of mode `virtualxid`
3. now the db waits for the application to send the next statement/s (until it receives `COMMIT` or `ROLLBACK`) - and then it will release the exclusive lock of mode `virtualxid`
4. but for some reason it does not get anymore statements:
   I think that the node.js event-loop is blocked - because at the time, when we see these locks, the node.js application does not log anymore statements. But the webserver still gets requests and reported some `upstream timed out` requests.

Does this make sense (I'm really not sure about 2. and 3.)?
Why would all transactions block at the beginning? Is this just coincidence or is the displayed SQL maybe wrong?

BTW: In this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44908655/1041641) I found, that we can set [idle_in_transaction_session_timeout](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-IDLE-IN-TRANSACTION-SESSION-TIMEOUT) so that these transactions will be released after a timeout - which is great, but I try to understand what's causing this issue.

Comment: You are not executing a loose `BEGIN` somewhere in your application, are you? If it were all part of method `tx` of the `pg-promise` library then the following queries should be following. Maybe your transaction logic fails to execute the queries relevant to the transaction, for some reasons?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The transactions are not blocking at all. The database is waiting for the application to send the next statement.

The lock on the transaction ID is just a technique for transactions to block each other, even if they are not contending for a table lock (for example, if they are waiting for a row lock): each transaction holds an exclusive lock on its own transaction ID, and if it has to wait for a concurrent transaction to complete, it can just request a lock on that transaction's ID (and be blocked).

If all transactions look like this, then the lock must be somewhere in your application; the database is not involved.

When looking for processes blocked in the database, look for rows in `pg_locks` where `granted` is false.

Answer (score 1):

Your interpretation is correct.  As for why it is happening, that is hard to say.  It seems like there is some kind of bug (maybe an undetected deadlock) in your application, or maybe in nodes.js or pg-promise.  You will have to debug at that level.

Comment: There cannot be any deadlock in the library, or it would have been discovered years ago. It's gotta be in the app.

Comment: @vitaly-t I also don't think that it's caused by pg-promise. I guess it may be infrastructure related: e.g. a TCP socket that's blocked, or the filesystem blocks (e.g. when some part tries to write a log-file or to stdout/err).
But maybe you have some idea/hint, why all calls could block after the `BEGIN` statements: I can't find any  `BEGIN` in the application, so this is done by pg-promise - but after that it should immediately send the application query, right?

Answer (score 1):

As expected the problems were caused by our application code. Transactions were used incorrectly:

- One of the REST endpoints started a new transaction right away, using [Database.tx()](https://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/Database.html#tx).
- This transaction was passed down multiple levels, but one function in the chain had an error and passed `undefined` instead of the transaction to the next level
- the lowest repository level function started a new transaction (because the transaction parameter was `undefined`), by using [Database.tx()](https://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/Database.html#tx) a second time

This started to fail, under heavy load:

- The connection pool size was set to 10
- When there were many simultaneous requests for this endpoint, we had a situation where 10 of the requests started (opened the outer transaction) and had not yet reached the repository code that will request the 2nd transaction.
- When these requests reached the repository code, they request a new (2nd) connection from the connection-pool. But this call will block because there are currently all connections in use.
- So we have a nasty application level deadlock

So the **solution** was to fix the application code (the intermediate function must pass down the transaction correctly). Then everything works.

Moreover I strongly **recommend to set** a sensible **idle_in_transaction_session_timeout** and **connection-timeout**. Then, even if such an application-deadlock is introduced again in future versions, the application can recover automatically after this timeout.
Notes:

- pg-postgres before v 10.3.4 contained a [small bug #682](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise/issues/682#issuecomment-565757120) related to the `connection-timeout`
- pg-promise before version 10.3.5 could not reocver from an `idle-in-transaction-timeout` and left the connection in a broken state: see [pg-promise #680](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise/issues/680)

Basically there was another issue: there was no need to use a transaction - because all functions were just reading data: so we can just use [Database.task()](https://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/Database.html#task) instead of [Database.tx()](https://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/Database.html#tx)

Comment: [The issue with the timeout declaration](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise/issues/682) has since been resolved in pg-promise.