# How to handle idle_in_transaction_session_timeout?

Tags: pg-promise

When we set [idle_in_transaction_session_timeout](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-IDLE-IN-TRANSACTION-SESSION-TIMEOUT), the database will terminate connections that are idle for some time.
This works as expected, but I wonder how we should deal with this situation in the aplication code.
We are using pg-promise `10.3.1`.

**Details** of the test:

- we set the connection pool size to `1`, so that we only have a single session
- we set the for the idle-transaction-session-timeout to `2.5` sec:
  `SET idle_in_transaction_session_timeout TO 2500`

  - now the active transaction will be in state `idle in transaction`:
    see [What can cause “idle in transaction” for “BEGIN” statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59162112/what-can-cause-idle-in-transaction-for-begin-statements)
- now we start a transaction and sleep for `5` seconds
- after `2.5`sec the database will terminate the session and send an error to the client:
  `pgp-error error: terminating connection due to idle-in-transaction timeout`
- after another `2.5`sec the transactional code tries to send a query (via the already terminated session), and this fails as expected:
  `dbIdle failed Error: Client has encountered a connection error and is not queryable`

  - then pg-promise will try to rollback the transaction which will also fail (also expected, I guess)
- **But now we start a new query and also this query fails** with
  `dbCall failed Client has encountered a connection error and is not queryable`

  - is this expected? I was hoping that pg-promise can somehow remove the "broken" connection from the pool and that we could get a new one
  - obvously this is not the case, so how should we deal with this situation: i.e. how to recover, so that we can send new queries to the database?

**Code example**:

```js
import pgPromise, { IMain } from "pg-promise";
import * as dbConfig from "./db-config.json";
import { IConnectionParameters } from "pg-promise/typescript/pg-subset";

const cll = "pg";
console.time(cll);

const pgp: IMain = pgPromise({
  query(e) {
    console.timeLog(cll,`> ${e.query}`);
  },
  error(e, ctx) {
    console.timeLog(cll,"pgp-error", e);
  }
});

const connectParams: IConnectionParameters = {
  ...dbConfig,
  application_name: "pg-test",
  max: 1
};
const db = pgp(connectParams);

/**
 * @param timeoutMs 0 is no timeout
 */
async function setDbIdleInTxTimeout(timeoutMs: number = 0) {
  await db.any("SET idle_in_transaction_session_timeout TO $1;", timeoutMs);
}

async function dbIdle(sleepTimeSec: number) {
  console.timeLog(cll, `starting db idle ${sleepTimeSec}`);
  const result = await db.tx(async t => {
    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, sleepTimeSec * 1000));
    return t.one("Select $1 as sleep_sec", sleepTimeSec);
  });
  console.timeLog(cll, result);
}

async function main() {
  await setDbIdleInTxTimeout(2500);
  try {
    await dbIdle(5);
  } catch (e) {
    console.timeLog(cll, "dbIdle failed", e);
  }
  try {
    await db.one("Select 1+1 as res");
  } catch (e) {
    console.timeLog(cll, "dbCall failed", e);
  }
}

main().finally(() => {
  pgp.end();
});
```

**Console outpu**t (removed some useless lines):

```
"C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" D:\dev_no_backup\pg-promise-tx\dist\index.js
pg: 23.959ms > SET idle_in_transaction_session_timeout TO 2500;
pg: 28.696ms starting db idle 5
pg: 29.705ms > begin
pg: 2531.247ms pgp-error error: terminating connection due to idle-in-transaction timeout
    at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:182:23) {
  name: 'error',
  severity: 'FATAL',
  code: '25P03',
}
pg: 2533.569ms pgp-error Error: Connection terminated unexpectedly
pg: 5031.091ms > Select 5 as sleep_sec
pg: 5031.323ms pgp-error Error: Client has encountered a connection error and is not queryable
pg: 5031.489ms > rollback
pg: 5031.570ms pgp-error Error: Client has encountered a connection error and is not queryable
pg: 5031.953ms dbIdle failed Error: Client has encountered a connection error and is not queryable
pg: 5032.094ms > Select 1+1 as res
pg: 5032.164ms pgp-error Error: Client has encountered a connection error and is not queryable
pg: 5032.303ms dbCall failed Error: Client has encountered a connection error and is not queryable

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: `is this expected? I was hoping that pg-promise can somehow remove the "broken" connection from the pool and that we could get a new one`. Yes. Broken connection is removed when the transaction ends/closes. You cannot get a new connection for the current transaction, there is no such thing, i.e. each transaction context is connection-bound.

Comment: @vitaly-t Note sure, I understand: In `dbIdle()` the transaction `t` fails, and thus the current (broken) connection will be removed from the pool, right? After that we call `db.one()`: Shouldn't this get a new connection from the pool (and execute without explicit transaction: i.e. pg-promise does not send `BEGIN`, just the statement and postgres will execute this statement in a new implicit transaction)?

Comment: [This provision](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise/blob/master/lib/connect.js#L59) should fully release a connection that had a query fail on account of a bad connection. So if transaction fails because of the connection, the next query outside of the transaction should get a fresh connection.

Comment: @vitaly-t: Then my example should work, right? I've forked pg-promise and added a new [test](https://github.com/tmtron/pg-promise/blob/master/test/idle-in-transaction-session-timeout.spec.js#L48). This is basically the same as the code in this question and it also fails. So is it a bug in pg-promise (or node-postgres)?

Comment: I've reported an issue for pg-promise [#680](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise/issues/680)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [issue #680](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise/issues/680#issuecomment-573433593) has been fixed in pg-promise `10.3.5`